# Adding any two numberic tuples in swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have created one function to add tuples which looks like (Int, Int).

```
func +<T : Numeric> (x: (T, T), y: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (x.0 + y.0, x.1 + y.1)
}
```

It works for `(10, 20) + (15, 15)`

Now what I need is to make an advancement to function to accept any variable length tuples of **same length**.

How is possible way?

At the end `(12) + (23)` and `(10, 12, 16) + (11, 36, 25)` should work.

Comment: Any particular reason for using tuples? What happens when the tuples are of unequal length?

Comment: You can solve this with Variadic parameters: Here is a great article about it https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/variadic-functions-swift-54ce99a55c1d

Comment: @Jonathan it's not possible to create a Variadic tuple.

Comment: @Woodstock of course it works with tuple

Comment: @Woodstock I tried it out and it worked

Comment: @Jonathan weird, I did the same and got a compiler error. What syntax did you use?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri i think he want this only for equal length

Comment: Here i have this code: `func doSomethin(_ o1: (x: Int, y: Int)...) {
    for x in o1 {
        print(x)
    }
}

doSomethin((x: 3, y: 4),(x: 5, y: 5),(x: 6, y: 1))
`

Comment: @Woodstock (comment above)

Comment: @Jonathan that is not what OP wants. P.S - you can edit comments.

Comment: @Woodstock the Problem isn't that it wont works with tuple.. it works with tuple! But the problem is, that only ONE variadic paramerter per function possible is

Comment: @Woodstock Yes I know that it isnt a answer for OP but its a Idea how to do it... due to the fact that only one variadic parameter per function possible is, this dont work

Comment: @Jonathan no. It is completely wrong is what i was trying to say. He wants the number of elements to be variable inside the tuple, not a variable number of tuples. Also, i'm not Woodstock btw. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @RakeshaShastri so it seems you are a mystery :D But okay, I thougth he wants the number of tuple... But yes, that makes sense,haha xD Because at an operator you can only have to values (lhs and rhs)

Answer (score 2):

Tuples need to have their number of elements determined at compile time, thus a variadic-like function won't work. You'll need to add overrides for the `+` operator, for each tuple size you need to support:

```
func +<T : Numeric> (x: (T, T), y: (T, T)) -> (T, T) {
    return (x.0 + y.0, x.1 + y.1)
}

func +<T : Numeric> (x: (T, T, T), y: (T, T, T)) -> (T, T, T) {
    return (x.0 + y.0, x.1 + y.1, x.2 + y.2)
}

func +<T : Numeric> (x: (T, T, T, T), y: (T, T, T, T)) -> (T, T, T, T) {
    return (x.0 + y.0, x.1 + y.1, x.2 + y.2, x.3 + y.3)
}

// and so on, ...
```

---

Alternatively, you can switch to other data types, like arrays, which allow a dynamic number of items:

```
infix operator ++ 

func ++<T: Numeric>(_ lhs: [T], _ rhs: [T]) -> [T] {
    return zip(lhs, rhs).map { $0.0 + $0.1 }
}

print([10, 12, 16] ++ [11, 36, 25]) // [21, 48, 41]
```

Caveats of this approach:

- you need to use a different operator, since is `+` already defined for arrays, and it concatenates the arrays instead of individually summing the corresponding elements
- if the two arrays have different sizes, then the result will have the size of the smaller arrays of the two input ones.

Comment: use any kind other than tuples, but keep it as single function.

Comment: its showing an error: operator implementation without matching operator declaration

Comment: @Saranjith did you copy the `infix operator ++` part?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array` solution as suggested by @Cristik or you can also make use of closure returning variadic function like:

```
func add<T : Numeric>(_ a: T...) -> (_ b: T...) -> [T] {
    return { (b: T...) -> [T] in
        return zip(a, b).map { $0.0 + $0.1 }
    }
}

let sum = add(1, 2,3)(4, 5, 6)

print(sum)
```